# revert logical partitions to original disk

Tags: linux, partition, disk-usage, fdisk

I have a disk that somehow split into what appear to be logical partitions, but I am unsure. How to revert to the original disk?

Here is the list of drives shown by `fdisk -l`:

```
/dev/mmcblk0
/dev/mmcblk0boot0
/dev/mmcblk0boot1
```

`lsblk` identifies each of these as disks, but according to `blkid`, each of them have a `PTUUID`.

Comment: Was drive not always gpt partitioned? PartUUID is shown with both MBR(msdos) and gpt partiitoning. But MBR uses a default set of partuuids. Best to show in question blkid and `lsblk -f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/dev/mmcblk0boot` devices are not "normal" partitions, these are special devices, so called [MMC boot partitions](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/mmc/mmc-dev-parts.txt) and are used to store parts of the bootloader on ARM boards for example. Ignore these "partitions" and create new partitions (if you need/want them) on the `/dev/mmcblk0` device, these partitions will be named `/dev/mmcblk0pX`.